# How to dynamically show a notification on html if attempts to login

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a simple spring mvc app. There are users stored in the db. I have a html page with 2 textfields and a button (username, password and submit). The user is able to log in if the username and password is in the database but if it is not, I'd like to show a small message like `User does not exist` besides the text field. This is what my html page looks at the moment.

```
<form action="/login" th:object="${customer}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{username}" id="username" />
                <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"> Username Error</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{password}" id="password" />
                <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"> Password Error</p>
            </div>

            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

At the moment, it does show some validation (i.e. when the user does not enter anything or if the user enters less than 2 characters) but I can't seem to get the notification to show. I tried adding this to my controller (its a snippet of the controller):

```
if(customerUsingQuery != null){
            ...
        }else{
            bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("customer","User does not exist in database."));

            resultTemplate = HOME_TEMPLATE;
        }
```

But the binding result doesn't seem to appear on the form.

Answer (score 0):

To display the error next to a field, use `FieldError`. Example for *username* field:

```java
bindingResult.addError(new FieldError(bindingResult.getObjectName(), "username", "User does not exist in database."));
```

Note: On authentication failure, it is best practice to not show if the users exists in system, only that credentials were bad.

To show all errors for form, including `ObjectError`s, use Thymeleaf code like:

```xml
<p th:each="err : ${#fields.allErrors()}" th:text="${err}">Invalid input.</p>
```